# C: Tokenize a string, counting commas as tokens

Tags: c, scanf, tokenize, strtok

I have to write, as an exercise, a very simple assembler for a made-up processor.
This processor has instructions with zero, one, or two operands. For example:

```
HELLO: add r7, B
```

In this instruction, `HELLO` is a label that is defined on this line, `add` is the instruction mnemonic, `r7` means "register #7", and `B` is a reference to a label defined somewhere else.

This line has to be broken into the following tokens:

```
((LABELDEF "HELLO") (INSTRUCTION "add") (REGISTERREF 7) (COMMA) (LABELREF "B"))
```

What gives me trouble is the comma between the operands. According to the spec, the comma may or may not be surrounded by whitespace on either side. (As opposed to the colon at the end of `HELLO:`, which must be adjacent to the label.) I think the comma has to be parsed as a separate token, because it is a mandatory part of the syntax and can't be treated as whitespace.

I came up with several implementation options:

- **A regular expression**: the obvious choice, but regular expressions are not part of the standard C library and the assignment says I can't use any additional libraries.
- **`strtok()`**: requires some delimiter characters (e.g. `' '`, `'\t'`) between consecutive tokens, which may not exist between the comma and the operands before and after it.
- **`sscanf()`**: unless I'm missing something, the `%s` specifier only stops reading when it sees whitespace, which, again, may not be there when there are two operands separated by a comma.
- Some combination or variation of the previous two options.
- **A custom state machine**: requires a lot more code than the preceding options, and I'm on a very tight schedule.

What is the best option in your opinion? Can you please share your experience in similar projects?

Comment: Instead of `%s` try using the other string specifier of the `sscanf()` function, the `%[` specifier, which can be used to read only strings containing a specified set of characters (or inversely only the characters that were not specified), for example with it you could try to read only commas and use the return of `sscanf()` to know if it successfully read a comma.

Comment: I was going to say "use flex" but I guess that would count as an external library. However, if you take a look at the handbuilt implementations of lexical analysers used in the example section of the [Bison manual](https://www.gnu.org/software/bison/manual/html_node/Mfcalc-Lexer.html), you'll see that if you just sit down and write a custom lexer, you'll have it done in no time. Advice: write and *debug* your lexer before you start using it

Comment: regex: like bringing a cannon to a watergun fight, strtok(): i always get yelled at for using it because it's not threadsafe, sscanf(): seems like a little much. I would simply parse it myself using nothing but a loop. if it's a well-defined structure, then if anything is missing, you can easily say "missing colon at position ..." -- you can't do that with any of the other methods.

Comment: Read the line with `fgets()` and then parse the line with various `sscanf(s, "...%n"`.

Comment: For production-quality code, write the custom tokenizer. For quick and dirty code, use `strchr` to find the comma. Replace the comma with a zero byte. Then use `strtok` on the two strings: before and after the comma. Of course, you have to handle the case where `strchr` doesn't find a comma. And because this is quick and dirty, you aren't handling multiple commas.